# How to pass an optional argument in Mongoose/MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query:

```
Documents.find({
    $and: [
      {
        user_id: {$nin: 
          myUserId
        }
      },
      { date: { $gte: dateMax, $lt: dateMin } },
      {documentTags: {$all: tags}}
    ],
  })
```

What I'm trying to do is make the documentTags portion of the query optional. I have tried building the query as follows:

```
let tags = " ";
    if (req.body.tags) {
        tags = {videoTags: {$all: req.body.tags}};
    }

let query = {
        $and: [
          {
            user_id: {$nin: 
              myUserId
            }
          },
          { date: { $gte: dateMax, $lt: dateMin } },
          tags
        ],
      }
```

and then `Document.find(query)`. The problem is no matter how I modify tags (whether undefined, as whitespace, or otherwise) I get various errors like `$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects` and `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined`.

Is there a way to build an optional requirement into the query?

I tried the option below and the query is just returning everything that matches the other fields. For some reason it isn't filtering by tags. I did a `console.log(queryArr)` and `console.log(query)` get the following respectively:

```
[
  { user_id: { '$nin': [Array] } },
  {
    date: {
      '$gte': 1985-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
      '$lt': 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
    }
  },
  push: { documentTags: { '$all': [Array] } }
]
```

console.log(query)

```
{
  '$and': [
    { user_id: [Object] },
    { date: [Object] },
    push: { documentTags: [Object] }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it wasn't working. Basically, when you do `myVar.push` it creates a `key-value pair` such as `[1,2,3,push:value]`. This would work if you needed to append a k-v pair in that format, but you'll have difficulty using it in a query like mine. The right way for me turned out to be to use `concact` which `appends` the array with just the value that you set, rather than a k-v pair.

```
if (req.body.tags){
    queryArgs = queryArgs.concat({documentTags: {$all: tags}});
}
let query = {
    $and: queryArgs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Instead you could construct the object outside the query and just put the constructed query in `$and` when done..

```
let queryArr = [
                 {
                    user_id: {$nin: myUserId}
                 },
                 { date: { $gte: dateMax, $lt: dateMin } }
               ];

    if (req.body.tags) {
        queryArr.push({videoTags: {$all: req.body.tags}});
    }

let query = {
        $and: queryArr
      }
```

Now you can control the query by just pushing object into the query Array itself.

Comment: I thought it was working but then I printed to console the values of queryArr and for some reason all of the variables are being saved as `[object]`. I've updated my question to show the data in the args and of course Mongo is not returning the right info